# How to retrieve all variable names within a netcdf using GDAL

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf, gdal

I am struggling to find a way to retrieve metadata information from a FILE using GDAL.
Specifically, I would like to retrieve the band names and the order in which they are stored in a given file (may that be a GEOTIFF or a NETCDF).

For instance, if we follow the description within the GDAL documentation, we have the "GetMetaData" method from the gdal.Dataset (see [here](https://gdal.org/api/gdaldataset_cpp.html#_CPPv411GDALDataset) and [here](https://gdal.org/tutorials/multidimensional_api_tut.html)). Despite this method returning a whole set of information regarding the dataset, it does not provide the band names and the order that they are stored within the given FILE. As a matter of fact, it seems to be an old problem (from 2015) that seems not to be solved yet (more info [here](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2015-February/041123.html)). As it seems, "R" language has already solved this problem (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586482/how-to-extract-variable-names-from-a-netcdf-file-in-r)), though Python hasn't.

Just to be thorough here, I know that there are other Python packages that can help in this endeavour (e.g., xarray, rasterio, etc.); nevertheless, it would be important to be concise with the set of packages that one should use in a single script. Therefore, I would like to know a definite way to find the band (a.k.a., variable) names and the order they are stored within a single FILE using gdal.

Please, let me know your thoughs in this regard.

Below, I present a starting point for solving this Issue, in which a file is opened by GDAL (creating a Dataset object).

```
from gdal import Dataset
from osgeo import gdal

OpeneddatasetFile = gdal.Open(f'NETCDF:{input}/{file_name}.nc:' + var)

if isinstance(OpeneddatasetFile , Dataset):
    print("File opened successfully")


# here is where one should be capable of fetching the variable (a.k.a., band) names
# of the OpeneddatasetFile.
# Ideally, it would be most welcome some kind of method that could return a dictionary 
# with this information

# something like:

# VariablesWithinFile = OpeneddatasetFile.getVariablesWithinFileAsDictionary()
```

Comment: Try `gdal.Info()` : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/336769/154461 . You will have to explore the dictionary for the required info.

Comment: Except that I believe `gdal.Info()` requires an open dataset object rather than a path string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a way to retrieve variable names from the NETCDF file using GDAL, and that is thank's to the comments given by Robert Davy above.

I have organized the code into a set of functions to help its visualization. Notice that there is also a function for reading metadata from the NETCDF, which returns this info in a dictionary format (see the "readInfo" function).

```
from gdal import Dataset, InfoOptions
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np


def read_data(filename):

    dataset = gdal.Open(filename)

    if not isinstance(dataset, Dataset):
        raise FileNotFoundError("Impossible to open the netcdf file")

    return dataset


def readInfo(ds, infoFormat="json"):
    "how to: https://gdal.org/python/"

    info = gdal.Info(ds, options=InfoOptions(format=infoFormat))

    return info


def listAllSubDataSets(infoDict: dict):

    subDatasetVariableKeys = [x for x in infoDict["metadata"]["SUBDATASETS"].keys()
                              if "_NAME" in x]

    subDatasetVariableNames = [infoDict["metadata"]["SUBDATASETS"][x]
                               for x in subDatasetVariableKeys]

    formatedsubDatasetVariableNames = []

    for x in subDatasetVariableNames:

        s = x.replace('"', '').split(":")[-1]
        s = ''.join(s)
        formatedsubDatasetVariableNames.append(s)

    return formatedsubDatasetVariableNames


if "__main__" == __name__:

    filename = "netcdfFile.nc"
    ds = read_data(filename)

    infoDict = readInfo(ds)

    infoDict["VariableNames"] = listAllSubDataSets(infoDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get an overview of the available subdatasets or "variable names" in a netcdf by doing:

```
ds = gdal.Open(filename)
subdatasets = ds.GetSubDatasets()
```

`subdatasets` will be a list of tuples which contain; (1) the path to the respective variable in the format of `"NETCDF:filename:var"` and; (2) some information on the variable such as dimension sizes and datatype.

So after that you can open a specific variable (e.g. the first one in the list) like this:

```
sub_ds = gdal.Open(subdatasets[0][0])
```